# Displaying Error messages in production for internal projects

Tags: c#, web-applications, web-deployment, production-environment

Is it a good idea to display error messages in Production webpage for internal projects with in the organization? I thought its a good option as they are not public facing web pages. End user can take a screenshot of error page and send to developer for support/fixing. Am I thinking really wrong? How can I make code show up based on environments and hide in production environment?

Comment: This really depends on use case scenario, and is a rather broad question. Depending on the scale of your application, you can write logs to files, or to a cache system that will be fetchable via a secured web interface.

Answer (score 1):

1) This question is oppinion-based and generally frowned upon at stackoverflow.

2) I like the question, so: 
Yes, it is a good idea to inform the user what went wrong. I do it because otherwise the users are more frustrated. The smart ones can even sometimes fix the problem with their admin.

**On the other hand**, the detailed information like stack trace and detailed information of some low-level API is not useful for the user. That should be logged to a log, given a timestamp or an ID, and only this reference should be displayed to the user in the error message so the admin can look it up and analyze the logs.